# GRUB in USB windows in a subfolder

Tags: usb, windows, grub

I'm creating a set of scripts for a multiboot USB, using **GRUB** as a **bootloader**.

I want to add **Windows installers**.

1. *I can boot* the Windows, extracting the files in the USB, *only* if the files are in the **root partition**.
2. If I want to add two Windows installers, say Windows 7 and Windows 10, I have to create **two partitions** for each *(I have done and it works fine)*.

Now, it would be perfect if, instead of creating partitions for each system, I could **place the windows files in subfolders**, and point the **GRUB** entries to them.

Like:

```
#root_usb/windows7/<windows files>


menuentry 'Windows 7 installer' {
  set root='(hd0,1)'
  insmod ntldr
  ntldr /windows7/bootmgr
}
```

Which, obviously, does not work.

**Question:**

Is it possible, using **GRUB**, to call windows installers in a subfolder? Or should I use other software, like **Grub4dos**?